# Search Builder broken with search for Member Since

Tags: search-builder

Take a look at the screenshot below. I am searching for "Member since $date" and getting seriously broken results.

CiviCRM 5.20.1 on Wordpress 5.3.2

[image]

Comment: It does seem broken. I'd file a lab ticket. It's working on advanced search so seems specific to search builder.

Comment: Thanks. I have a custom report that is also not working - wondering if something on of the search backends isn't work. Also, seems a prime opportunity to do some refactoring to cleanup the many search options